# Get The Max Value of double from List<object> in .Net 2.0

Tags: list, .net-2.0

```
  List<object> lst = new List<object>();
```

How can I get max value from this list it contains double value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double max = double.MinValue;
foreach (object item in lst)
{
   if (item is double)
   {
       if ((double)item > max)
       {
           max = (double)item;
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would use [LINQBridge](http://code.google.com/p/linqbridge) to get you LINQ goodness:

```
double max = lst.OfType<double>().Max();
```

It might be overkill to use LINQBridge just for a single "find the maximum element" query, but of course you can then use it everywhere else in your project too... and your code will be more idiomatic when you eventually move off .NET 2 :)

Comment: @SOF User: It is if you use LINQBridge, yes... that's the whole point of LINQBridge, to let you use LINQ from .NET 2.